# MVC3 Model Editing - incorrect/missing values returning to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to build an View for editing one of my models in MVC, however when I get the edited Model in my "Edit" method, some properties are null, and some have incorrect values.

I've have it stripped down to a pretty basic example, but I still can't figure out what's going on.  When I edit my model, and click save, the model returned in the controller has the wrong boolean value (it's always false).  Also, my Parent and IList<> objects are always null.  Really, I would never want to edit those fields, on this model I only want to edit the Name and Active properties.  However, it's being returned as null, and my fluent NHibernate SaveOrUpdate() method attempts to remove them.

So my question is, why are my boolean fields always returning as false.  And why are my Parent and IList fields always coming back null?

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    var clientDetail = clientRepository.Get(id);
    return View(clientDetail);
}
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Client editedItem) {
    try {
        ValidateModel(editedItem);
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid) {
            clientRepository.SaveOrUpdate(editedItem);
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Need to show some type of warning here...perhaps in a view bag.
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And my View:

```
@model Models.Client

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Model:

```
public class Client {
    [Display(Name="Client ID")]
    [DataType("Url")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "../../Client/Details/{0}/")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Editable(false)]
    public virtual IList<Login> Logins { get; set; }

}
```

UPDATE: Generated HTML

```
<form action="/Client/Edit/17" method="post">
  <table class="editor-table">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10em">
        <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
          * <label for="Id">Client ID:</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Client ID must be a number." data-val-required="The Client ID field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="text" value="17"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Id" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="editor-table">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10em">
        <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
          <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="Dummy Client"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="editor-table">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10em">
        <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
          * <label for="Active">Active:</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="check-box" type="checkbox" checked="'checked'"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Active" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table><input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Editor Templates:

Template:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml) { 
    <table class="editor-table">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10em">
            <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
                @(ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired ? "*" : "")
                <label for="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName">@ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName():</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @RenderSection("EditContent")
                @Html.ValidationMessage("", "*")
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Boolean Template:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_Template.cshtml";
}

@section EditContent {
    @if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType) { 
        <select class="list-box tri-state" >
            <option value="@Model.HasValue ? " : "selected='selected'">Not Set</option>
            <option value="@Model.HasValue && @Model.Value ? "selected='selected'">True</option>
            <option value="@Model.HasValue && !@Model.Value ? "selected='selected'">False</option>
        </select>
    } else {
        <input class="check-box" id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" type="checkbox" @(Model ? "checked='checked'" : "") />
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post method does not need the `id` parameter, just the Client object is enough, the default model binder is probably getting a little confused with that extra parameter.

Comment: @Matt - thanks for the tip. However that didn't have any impact on the issue.  The edited model is making it into the Controller, however the boolean fields are always returning false, and my complex types are returned as null.

Comment: Can you show the HTML that gets generated by the view? It looks like `EditorForModel` is not generating the form fields as expected.

Comment: @Matt - I just updated the post with the generated HTML.  One thing I just thought about is I'm using EditorTemplates.  Not sure if this has any impact on this or not.  For the most part, they're just like the ones in Brad Wilson's post on Display and Editor templates

Comment: Why ViewData.Model = clientDetail; and not return View(clientDetail);

Comment: @Derek - Thanks for another tip.  Still learning as I'm going here..

Comment: I know the output for the <input> tags needs to include the name attribute for the Default Model Binder to do its job. Why your custom templates are not including it, I don't know. But that is where the disconnect is. I agree, your templates look just like Brad's, but I've not done enough with custom editor templates to be really helpful here.

Comment: @Matt - I just added the id and name attributes on my input, however it's still returning false to my controller.  I'll update my template above with the change

Comment: `<input class="check-box" type="checkbox" checked="'checked'">` I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be `'checked'` but just `checked` without the single quotes - which means somewhere the output is getting screwed up

Comment: If your POST data has a field like 'Active=true', then the model binder should pick up on that. Is it possible you're using a cached copy of the view? You can put a break point in the action and look inside `Request.Form` to see the data that is actually getting sent up.

Comment: @Matt - I checked Request.Form and it has the following:  {Id=17&Name=Dummy+Client&Active=on}

Comment: Not an answer but you might want to create ViewModels for display and input.  Then map your domain entities to ViewModels.

Comment: @Brosto -- then what you need to add is `value="true"` to the `<input>` tag, the model binder doesn't know how to to turn "on" into a boolean.

Comment: That should get your action to work, however I think a real long term fix is to truly grock edit templates. I don't think all this extra massaging of the template should be needed.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks for your help.  I'll mess around with this more on Monday.  It's 5:00 on a Friday...time for a break! ;-)  Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with my boolean fields by changing the EditorTemplate to a simple:  @Html.CheckBox("",Model).  While this won't work for nullable Boolean's, in my case I didn't have any of those to worry about.  This is what my new editor template looks like:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_Template.cshtml";
}

@model Boolean

@section EditContent {
    @Html.CheckBox("", Model)
}
```

And the generated Html:

```
<table class="editor-table">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10em">
            <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
                *
                <label for="Active">Active:</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
    <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Active field is required." id="Active" name="Active" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Active" type="hidden" value="false" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Active" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hopefully this helps someone else avoid what I went through, but it definitely was a learning experience.  Everyone, thanks for all the helpful advice above.